# Customizing AirDrop receive menu

Tags: ios, airdrop

When receiving a PDF sent by AirDrop to an iOS device, after I accept the AirDrop request on the target device, I'm presented with a list of apps that can handle the file, as in the image below.

How can I customize that list?

How can I always save the file in Books?

[image]

Comment: @fsb, that is the "sharing menu", not the "receive menu".

Comment: You're correct, I misread your question.  I'm not aware of any way to customize the receiving apps.